# script editor in google sheets not emailing hyperlink

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-apps-script-editor

I am using script editor in google sheets to send out multiple emails. However, in the message, I have a hyperlink named "Click Here"
When emails are sent through the script editor, it sends "Click Here" text but not the hyperlink.

Thanks

Trent

Comment: Hi @Trent Sulz maybe you can add more #tag about your question, so the community can help you figure this out faster.

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant code from the script editor and any relevant Sheet data.  [There is not enough information yet.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)